# -bash: systemctl: command not found

Tags: linux, systemd, oracle-linux

I am tasked with migrating a Linux server (the system was installed around 2014) to a new OS. What ever I am typing is based on my limited understanding. Also, I found https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-migrate-linux-servers-part-1-system-preparation as a reference to find relevant codes for finding my present Linux server OS details, services, installed softwares, etc. I am executing the commands and Landed with following error:

My present code:

```
[root@bird]# uname -r
3.8.13-118.19.2.el6uek.x86_64
[root@bird]# cat /etc/issue
Oracle Linux Server release 6.10
Kernel \r on an \m
```

Error:

```
[root@bird]# systemctl list-units -t service
-bash: systemctl: command not found
```

Does it mean, my current linux server does not have `systemctl`? Which command should I use to get all the list of available services, softwares installed, etc?

Comment: Maybe old versions of Oracle Linux (as well as RedHat) don't use systemd. Try running this: `service --status-all`

Comment: It worked. Looks like it printed a lot of information.